# Error in running Ubuntu from my USB. My windows is corrupted

Tags: 12.04

I tried running Ubuntu 12.04 desktop from a usb, got an error back. Using ubuntu by running it virtually to recover my files, windows is kinda corrupted.

My computer specs:

Computer: hp pavillion dv 9000
OS: Windows vista 32 bit
CPU: AMD Athon X2
Graphics: NVIDIA Geforce Go 7150
Wireless: Broadcom

all the process shows ok onthe right until the squasfs errors like

```
28.267297: SQUASHFS error: zilb_inflate error, data probably corrupt
   "  324:               : squashfs_read_data failed to read block 0x275fcda4
   "  340:               : Unable to read fragment cache entry [275fcda]
   "  351:               :         "      page, bock 275fcda4, size 6eb7
```

So do I need to give anymore information, and please tell me there is a solution.

My finals are coming up and my assignments are stuck in the hardisk, crap imma fail.

Answer (score 2):

To restore the Windows Vista bootloader, you must first boot off your Windows Vista installation DVD.

If you have one of the many OEM computers that didn't come with a Vista installation disk, you can get the same effect with a Vista recovery disk, which you can download  or create from another Vista/7 computer (see this [page](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows7/Create-a-system-repair-disc) and this [tutorial](http://forums.techarena.in/guides-tutorials/1114725.htm)).

When you get to the Regional settings, select your Location/Keyboard setting then click next.

On the next page you must click on "Repair your computer."

On the next page, if it finds your Windows Vista installation, make sure it is UNSELECTED before clicking next.

Then click on "Command prompt". From there, type in the folowing:

```
bootrec.exe /fixboot

bootrec.exe /fixmbr
```

Now close the two windows and click "Restart."

Take out your Vista DVD and hopefully, you will be left with your Windows Vista Bootloader.

If you dont want also to restore Ubuntu

Boot into the Ubuntu 12.04 Live CD and click "Try Ubuntu without installing":

[image]

After the desktop is loaded, we need to mount the root partition so that we grant the live cd user read/write permissions on your system files and folders. Let's first identify the partition where Ubuntu is installed with this command:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Note: The Terminal can be started by pressing   **CTRL+ALT+T.**

The Ubuntu partition we will work on will be labeled with the word "Linux" as shown in the screenshot given below:

[image]
Run now this sequence of commands to mount the root partition:

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/ubuntu

sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/ubuntu
```

Then you need to mount these system folders to use them on your current desktop environment:

```
sudo mount --bind /dev /media/ubuntu/dev

sudo mount --bind /proc /media/ubuntu/proc

sudo mount --bind /sys /media/ubuntu/sys
```

Now chroot into your hard drive with this command:

```
sudo chroot /media/ubuntu
```

You have now read/write permissions on your root partition. To install GRUB2, you need to use one of these two commands:

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

or

```
grub-install --root-directory=/media/ubuntu /dev/sda
```

Note: the "sudo" is not required since you are logged in as root now. Also keep /dev/sda as is.

If the installation is successful, you will get these outputs:

**root@ubuntu:/#** `grub-install /dev/sda`

> Installation finished. No error reported.

Update GRUB2 with this command:

```
update-grub
```

Now Remove the Ubuntu installation CD and reboot your system to see if the GRUB2 boot menu is restored or not.

Comment: You are not going to install VISTA by this way. By this way you've gonna restor your bootloader and thus you can boot Windows Vista to get your data back and sure you are not in need for recovery now. your problem will be solved easily

Comment: ok I did not see the edit and pictures on your first post. For Ubuntu I selected "Trying without installing". When loading to the desktop, It checks for the battery state and other stuffs was ok until the errors                                 '28.267297: SQUASHFS error: zilb_inflate error, data probably corrupt'
      '324: : squashfs_read_data failed to read block 0x275fcda4'

" '340: : Unable to read fragment cache entry [275fcda]'

" '351: : " page, bock 275fcda4, size 6eb@#'

Comment: read this topic about the possible errors and causes https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SquashfsErrors